# using sqlite for replacing word by another word in a string

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I want to perform a simple query but with many time.
In my table, there are 3 cols:

id(int) needle(string) word(string)

needle can be any type of character, and is non English.

word is also any type of character, and is non English.

There are 3000 rows.

I can replace needle to word by simple query. but it is very slow, takes about 2s for 100 words. In what way can i improve the speed? thanks

Answer (score 4):

> I can replace needle to word by simple query. but it is very slow,
>   takes about 2s for 100 words. In what way can i improve the speed?
>   thanks

I suggest you to wrap your update statements into one `TRANSACTION` that rapidly increase your performance(tested by myself).

At first it rapidly increase your performace and second also your dealing with database becomes much more safer.

Here is basic snippet of **pseudo-code**:

```
try {
   db.beginTransaction(); // starting transaction
   // perform updates
   db.setTransactionSuccessful(); // marks transaction successful i.e. commit()
}
finally {
   if (db != null) {
      if (db.inTransaction()) {
         db.endTransaction();
      }
      db.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont say clear enough. I am not performing update statement. I have a string say 'apple, banana', and I want to show the image of apple and banana. The img path is in database. I want to query it. Again, the string 'apple, banana' is non english.